# How do I specify that phase should equal null OR junior Or senior using the or (Op.or / $or) operator for sequelize?

Tags: model, sequelize.js

How do I specify that phase should equal null OR junior Or senior using the or (Op.or / $or) operator for sequelize?

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('./_db');

const Student = db.define('student', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
    },
    phase: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: null,
      $or: [{ phase: null }, { phase: 'junior' }, { phase: 'senior' }],
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by 2 ways :

**Change the type of field to ENUM :**

```
phase: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM('junior', 'senior') ,
    defaultValue: null,
}

// ------------ OR -------------

phase: {
    type:   Sequelize.ENUM ,
    values: ['junior', 'senior'] ,
    defaultValue: null
}
```

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html)**

> OR

**Set validation :**

```
const Student = db.define('student', {
    ...
    phase: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: null,
    }
    ...
  } , {
    validate: {
        checkPhase() {
            if (!(this.phase === null || this.phase === 'junior' || this.longitude === 'senior')) {
                throw new Error('Phase value should be junior or senior')
            }
        }
    }
});
```